# Rotating a cube about an axis

Tags: three.js

In my program, I have done as:

```
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 0xff0000 ) );
object.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
var box = new THREE.BoxHelper( object, 0xffff00 );
scene.add(box);
```

Here,I first try to create a wireframe box and then rotate it by 90 degrees about x axis(line 2). But I don't see any change in box's orientation.

What is correct way of doing it?

Comment: After rotation of the object, try to call `object.updateMatrixWorld();`

Comment: Still no change.

Comment: The box itself is an axis-aligned bounding box. It won't rotate as you might expect.

Comment: noticed just now, if you rotate a _cube_ at 90 degrees, visually you'll have the same cube.

Answer (score 0):

Just set rotation of the cube at 90 degrees (here it's 45) and you'll have the same cube:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua",
  wireframe: true
}));
cube.position.set(0, 1, 0);
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.25;
scene.add(cube);

var box = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube, 0xff9900);
scene.add(box);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```